# MariaDb won't start debian 9

Tags: mariadb, debian-stretch

I just tried to make some changes in `my.cnf` like: `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `innodb_log_file_size`, `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`=0, and add "`skip-name-resolve`" 
and from that time, can't start the mariadb, even I have reverse all changes still won't work ....

I'm desperate because my shop not working, clear all of the mysql, install new, still do not start...

when i try to start or install get this errors:

```
Jun 27 12:28:36 server systemd[4311]: mariadb.service: Failed to change ownership of session keyring: Permission denied
Jun 27 12:28:36 server systemd[4311]: mariadb.service: Failed to set up kernel keyring: Permission denied
Jun 27 12:28:36 server systemd[4311]: mariadb.service: Failed at step KEYRING spawning /usr/bin/install: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /usr/bin/install could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The process /usr/bin/install could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned by this process is 13.
Jun 27 12:28:36 server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=237
Jun 27 12:28:36 server systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 27 12:28:36 server systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.33 database server.
-- Subject: Unit mariadb.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Unit mariadb.service has failed.
```

somebody can help me ? really don't know what to do....

tried to executed `/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld`, and start in safe mode... but still doesn't work

Comment: if you want to edit your post, do it against the formatted and readable version.

Comment: Did you look at MariaDB logfiles for errors?

Comment: Patrick Mevzek, have got something like this:

Comment: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
Using Linux native AIO
Using SSE crc32 instructions
Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
Completed initialization of buffer pool
Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
128 rollback segment(s) are active.
Waiting for purge to start
Percona XtraDB 5.6.36-82.1 started; log sequence number  
     Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started

Answer (score 0):

edit:
(tell your provider to) append

```
keyctl_chown errno 38
keyctl errno 38
```

to /usr/share/lxc/config/common.seccomp and restart your container.

Comment: sorry, I'm rookie, can you explain what need to do ?

Comment: keyctl_chown: command not found

Comment: It means edit the file /usr/share/lxc/config/common.seccomp and put those two lines at the end of it.

Comment: don't have this folder and this file...

Comment: not sure they will do this, but we will see... thanks for help, hope i will find cure for this bug quickly ;)  need sleep some ;)

Comment: they said that they don't use the LXC...

Comment: thanks for help, I have to reinstall the system..., and that fix the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

final edit:
This has been reported as bug no 865870, try upgrading your packages.

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: how to stop this now journalctl -f & ? ;)

Comment: type this: kill -9 %1

Comment: tried this command, don't work, have the same errors...

Comment: Did you run both commands, sequentially? You should omit the dollar sign in the beginning of the second command

Comment: yes, no reaction

Comment: ok, i edited my answer. try that

Comment: don't have LXC, what is that ?

Comment: check out my latest edit

Comment: check that before(don't work), and now, get: '/etc/init.d/mariadb: No such file or directory' maybe because it is not installed..

Comment: Type ls /etc/init.d and show me the results

Comment: Or check out my new edit

Comment: busybox-syslogd ,dovecot, hwclock.sh, modules_dep.sh, mountnfs-bootclean.sh,php7.0-fpm,   quota,rmnologin,screen-cleanup ,sudo          umountroot,wide-dhcpv6-client,apache-htcacheclean,checkfs.sh,fail2ban     irqbalance,motd,mountnfs.sh,plymouth,quotarpc,rpcbind,sendmail,trousers, unattended-upgrades,x11-common,apache2,checkroot-bootclean.sh,fetchmail,killprocs,mountall-bootclean.sh,mysql,plymouth-log,rcrsync,sendsigs,udev,urandom,xinetd,bootlogs,checkroot.sh,halt,kmod                mountall.sh,

Comment: networking,postfix,rc.local,rsyslog,single,ufw,uuidd,bootmisc.sh,cron,hdparm,maradns,mountdevsubfs.sh,nginx,procps,rcS,saned,skeleton,umountfs,vzquota,busybox-klogd,dbus,hostname.sh,maradns-zoneserver,mountkernfs.sh,php5-fpm,proftpd,reboot,saslauthd,ssh,umountnfs.sh,vzreboot

Comment: yeah tried this before, same results, fail2ban also don't start but this is not so important

Comment: this is a known bug, please read my latest edit

Comment: the service (my vps provider) said that because that is openvz, can't do any upgrade and that why this is not working with strech and the only way is to install whole system again.. don't like this vision, and this system with maria work fine before...

Comment: tell the provider to run my previously stated commands and it will work

Comment: yeah I saw it also, but there was no solution what to do... and how to fix it...

Comment: but i tried, and they don't work, also after upgrade ...